# laravel 5.5 group by doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, group-by, eloquent

I'm trying to get some data but I just get this error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'ms_mascotas.ms_razas.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `ms_razas.id`, `ms_razas.nombre`, `ms_mascotas.raza_id`, `ms_mascotas.id` from `ms_mascotas` inner join `ms_razas` on `ms_razas.id` = `ms_mascotas.raza_id` where `ms_razas.tipo_animal_id` = 1 group by `ms_mascotas.raza_id`)"

my query is this

```
$data=Mascota::select("ms_razas.id","ms_razas.nombre","ms_mascotas.raza_id","ms_mascotas.id")
       ->join("ms_razas","ms_razas.id","=","ms_mascotas.raza_id")
       ->where("ms_razas.tipo_animal_id",$id)
       ->groupBy("ms_mascotas.raza_id")
       ->get();
```

I've been reading about this error and it is related with the strict mode in the database file, strict is set to false by default, what should I do?

Comment: Place the group by after the `get()`

Comment: Or, add all the selected columns into the `groupBy()`

Comment: hi luis, now the error is gone, but the query isn't grouping the data

Comment: what solution you did?

Comment: I added grouby after get()

Comment: That one groups the collection. If you want to group the query results use the second one

Comment: `groupBy("ms_razas.id","ms_razas.nombre","ms_mascotas.raza_id","ms_mascotas.id")`

Comment: for some reason it does not work either

Comment: There can be multiple rows for each `ms_mascotas.raza_id` value. Which one do you want to get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem isn't caused by laravel but this is because **MySQL** doesn't permit the illegal query, because in standard **SQL-92**, the nonaggregated name column in the select list does not appear in the **GROUP BY**. [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

Actually, you better solve the solution with changing the query, but if you still want to use the same query, just go to your `config\database.php` and change the setting the database that you use

```
'strict' => false
```

Comment: strict is set to false by default in laravel 5.5

Comment: try your query in Database tool like mysql or postgresql.. Maybe your query is the problem

Comment: I don't know what happened but I compressed and decompress the project in my personal computer and when I entered again to the database file ,stric was set to true.

Answer (score 2):

Everything you select you must add in the group by, here is an example

```
 Mascota::select("ms_razas.id","ms_razas.nombre","ms_mascotas.raza_id","ms_mascotas.id")
       ->join("ms_razas","ms_razas.id","=","ms_mascotas.raza_id")
       ->where("ms_razas.tipo_animal_id",$id)
       ->groupBy("ms_razas.id","ms_razas.nombre","ms_mascotas.raza_id","ms_mascotas.id")
       ->get();
```

You need to have a full group by:

```
SELECT `name`, `type`, `language`, `code` 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `verified` = '1' 
GROUP BY `name`, `type`, `language`, `code` 
ORDER BY `count` DESC LIMIT 0, 25
```

> SQL92 requires that all columns (except aggregates) in the select clause is part of the group by clause. SQL99 loosens this restriction a bit and states that all columns in the select clause must be functionally dependent of the group by clause. MySQL by default allows for partial group by and this may produce non-deterministic answers, example:

```
create table t (x int, y int);
insert into t (x,y) values (1,1),(1,2),(1,3);
select x,y from t group by x;
+------+------+
| x    | y    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
+------+------+
```

I.e. A random y is select for the group x. One can prevent this behavior by setting `@@sql_mode`:

```
set @@sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';
select x,y from t group by x; 
ERROR 1055 (42000): 'test.t.y' isn't in GROUP BY
```

Comment: even this query doesn't work, what happen with this version of laravel?
`$data=Mascota::groupBy("raza_id")
       ->get();`